# Использование std::enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++

Почему при наследовании от `enable_shared_from_this` с модификатором `private`, следующий код приводит к выбросу исключения при вызове `shared_from_this`:

```
class A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    A(): std::enable_shared_from_this<A>()
    {

    }
    std::shared_ptr<A> getPtr()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};


 int main()
 {
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
    std::shared_ptr<A> a2 = a->getPtr();
 }
```

а если наследовать с модификатором `public` то все работает?

Comment: вам стоит почитать о спецификаторах `public`, `private` и `protected`

Answer (score 3):

Потому что: конструктор `std::enable_shared_from_this` защищенный, и, следовательно, конструировать его может только наследник. Закрытое наследование не делает целевой класс наследником. Целевой класс позволяет корректно создавать `std::shared_ptr` или `weak_ptr` с использованием указателя `this`,  он должен являться(а не просто использовать)  `std::enable_shared_from_this`(это есть требование), поэтому наследование должно быть открытым.

Comment: Сначала ознакомтесь с особенностьями сущности, только потом используйте его